# Times values same array in one JavaScript iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm

In my problem, I have an array like below

```
var R = [
  {R1 : 1},
  {R2 : 2},
  {R3 : 3}
];

var L = [
      {L1 : 100},
      {L2 : 200},
      {L3 : 300}
];
```

I want to make it like this

> (r1*l2*l3)+(r2*l1*l3)+(r3*l1*l2) / (l2*l3)+(l1*l3)+(l1*l2)

I've separated the iterations without its allies with this code

```
var x = 1;    
$.each(R, function(index, result_R){
  var nilaiR = parseInt(result_R["R"+x]);
  var y = 1;
  var cross = 0;
  $.each(l, function(index, result_L){
    if(x != y){
      console.log(result_L);
      //result is {l2:200},{l3:300},{l1:100},{l3:300},{l1:100}, {l2:200}
    }
    y++;
  })
  x++;
})
```

Comment: Is the length of the array ever not going to be 3? Otherwise just making a function that just uses the formula you give is a fine solution.

Comment: @swagrov hello, Surely the length of the array becomes 9, because I make it looping in the loop. would be 3 * 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've got a variable number of R and L items (L.length === R.length), this is my take using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=b).

To make my life easier, I've used [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to convert the arrays of objects into arrays of numbers:

```js
const R = [{R1: 1}, {R2: 2}, {R3: 3}];

const L = [{L1: 100}, {L2: 200}, {L3: 300}];

const r = R.map((o) => Object.values(o)[0]); // convert to array of numbers
const l = L.map((o) => Object.values(o)[0]); // convert to array of numbers

// iterate r and multiply each item by all items in l that don't have the same index, and sum the results
const numerator = r.reduce((sr, vr, ir) => sr + l.reduce(
  (sl, vl, il) => il !== ir ? sl * vl : sl, vr
), 0);

// iterate l and sum each multiplied pair
const denominator = l.reduce((s, v, i) => 
  s + l.slice(i + 1).reduce((ss, vv) => ss + v * vv, 0), 0);

console.log(numerator / denominator);
```

If you always have 3 items in R, and 3 in L, just convert the math formula into a function:

```js
const R = [{R1: 1}, {R2: 2}, {R3: 3}];
const L = [{L1: 100}, {L2: 200}, {L3: 300}];

const f = (R, L) => {
  const [r1, r2, r3] = R.map((o) => Object.values(o)[0]); // convert to array of numbers, and assign to variables
  const [l1, l2, l3] = L.map((o) => Object.values(o)[0]); // convert to array of numbers, and assign to variables

  return ((r1*l2*l3)+(r2*l1*l3)+(r3*l1*l2)) / ((l2*l3)+(l1*l3)+(l1*l2));
};

console.log(f(R, L));
```

And the ES5 version:

```js
var R = [{R1: 1}, {R2: 2}, {R3: 3}];
var L = [{L1: 100}, {L2: 200}, {L3: 300}];

function convertToNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(o) {
    return o[(Object.keys(o)[0])];
  });
}

function f(R, L) {
  var r = convertToNumbers(R);
  var l = convertToNumbers(L);

  return ((r[0]*l[1]*l[2])+(r[1]*l[0]*l[2])+(r[2]*l[0]*l[1])) / ((l[1]*l[2])+(l[0]*l[2])+(l[0]*l[1]));
};

console.log(f(R, L));
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works. I've tested and the results are good. can you translate es6 function to es5 function ?

Comment: @aeeeeeeng - enjoy.